# Word for "roughly horizontal" and "roughly vertical"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

A vertical line is one that makes 90 degrees to the horizon and a horizontal line is one that makes 0 degrees to the horizon.

Is there a single word that describes "roughly horizontal", i.e. less than 45 degrees to the horizon

And another single word that describes "roughly vertical", i.e. more than 45 degrees to the horizon?

Comment: _almost_ horizontal/vertical!

Comment: 'Plumb', derived from plumb line, can mean vertical and 'flat' can mean horizontal. Also the suffix '-ish' means approximate. This gives you two terms 'plumb-ish' and 'flattish', although I must admit that flattish is a lot more common than plumb-ish.

Comment: I don't think that anyone will think of a 44° degree tilted line as roughly vertical. You are looking for a word that captures the complete 88° degree range from +44° to - 44° that the line can be angled, right?  Please clarify this in your question. It might also be a better fit on Math.SE

Comment: @BoldBen, _flattish_ can be used for a _surface_ (and not for a _line_ as far as I know); plus it can mean _slightly bumpy_.

Comment: @alwayslearning I would agree that the surface definitions are more usual but 'flat' is the closest non-techical word I know in English. I don't believe that ordinary people would have used 'horizontal' before schooling was widespread, for example we say 'lying flat out' for lying supine. Also there is the expression 'flat-lining' for someone attached to ICU kit who has arrested and the displayed graphs go straight and horizontal, so 'flat' applies to lines in that context at least.

Comment: @BoldBen - "Plumb" means "*perfectly* vertical" (or as close to perfect as humanly possible) -- it is not approximate.  And a "flat wall" is not horizontal.

Comment: I suspect that "roughly vertical" and "roughly horizontal" (perhaps substituting another term for "roughly") is about the best you can do.

Comment: If x is the the angle to the horizon, "roughly horizontal" corresponds to tangent x < 1, and "roughly vertical" corresponds to tangent x >1. I know of no two single words for these two circumstances.

Comment: Are you looking for a word that can describe a geometric line, or something to describe objects, or...? Depending on how you want to use the terms, you might use *tall* vs *wide*, *upright* vs *sideways*, *portrait* vs *landscape*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> Bring me the board that's lying *sideways*.
>
> Bring me the board that's *standing up*.

If I did not guess right at the kind of sentence you're trying to come up with, then please edit your question to add some example sentences.